# Generating various email responses based on results from one Google Forms

Tags: gmail, google-forms

I have a google form that has multiple sections and a different set of questions depending on the answer to the first multiple choices. I want to be able to send an email and use a different body message for each of the sections. Below is a snippet of the code

```
function myFunction(e){
var accountType = e.values[1];
var personName = e.values[2];
var personAddress = e.values[3];
var businessName = e.values[4];
var businessAddress = e.values[5];
var charityName = e.values[6];
var charityAddress = e.values[7];
var subject = "Webform " + accountType + ;
var message = "Application received from " + personName + " of " + personAddress;
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message);
}
```

I need to have it send a different message (email body) when specific text has been entered into variable "accountType" will create a different email message (body)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use an if/else statement to achieve the desired outcome, threw it together quickly but it should look like what I have below:

```
  if (accountType = 'account_type-1') {
    var message = "Application received from " + personName + " of " + personAddress;
  } else {
    if (accountType = 'account_type-2') {
      var message = "Different Application received from " + personName + "of " + personAddress;
    }
  }
```